# How to select nested list with its ancestors in c#?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a nested model Countries which has cities. Cities has districts which has zones. I can get data from client as a nested model. So I want to select a zones with its ancestor like country, city and district.  I do not want to use 4* foreach to set Zone entity. Because, I need to iterate countries, then its cities and then its districts and finally its zones to set it. These method increase the "Time complexity". So, how can I set Zone entity using the following response model.

The Following is the response model

```
    {
   "Id":"208",
   "Name":"Türkiye",
   "Cities":[
      {
         "Id":"1",
         "Name":"Adana",
         "Districts":[
            {
               "Id":"1",
               "Name":"Aladağ",
               "Zones":[
                  {
                     "Id":"1",
                     "Name":"Merkez"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Id":"2",
               "Name":"Baraj Yolu",
               "Zones":[
                  {
                     "Id":"3",
                     "Name":"Merkez"
                  },
                  {
                     "Id":"2",
                     "Name":"Beyazevler Mah."
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

The followings are data model at MongoDb.

```
 public class Countries {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int? Order { get; set; }     
    public string FlagImage { get; set; }
    public List<Cities> Cities { get; set; }
}


public class Cities{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string CountryId { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }       
    public int? Order { get; set; }
    public List<Districts> Districts { get; set; }
}

public class Districts
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CountryId { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
    public string CityId { get; set; }
    public string CityName { get; set; }
    public List<Zones> Zones { get; set; }
}

 public class Zones
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CountryId { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
    public string CityId { get; set; }
    public string CityName { get; set; }
    public string DistrictId { get; set; }
    public string DistrictName { get; set; }
}

var newCities = response.Data.Where(i =>i.Cities != null)
                                         .SelectMany(i => i.Cities)
                                         .Select(a => new
                                            {
                                                CountryId = i.Id,
                                                CountryName = a.Name,
                                                Districts= a.Districts
                                            }).ToList();
```

The code above is to get just cities and its districts and ancestor. The error is here :

> "i does not exist in the current context."

Comment: can u keep `a` instead of `i` in `select`

Comment: What do you think a is? Cities = a.Districts?!

Comment: Why does a City have a CountryName property?! It smells...

Comment: @sriharsha error is same when I keep `i` instead of `a`.  @Bernoulli IT  It is not relational db. So I need keep Ids its own document (mongodb).

Comment: Try following :             var newCities = response.Data.Countries.Select(country => 
                country.Cities.SelectMany(city => city.Districts.SelectMany(district => district.Zones.Select(zone => new 
                { zone = zone,
                  district = district,
                  city = city,
                  country = country
                }).ToList() //zones
                ).ToList() //districts
                ).ToList()) //cities
                .ToList(); //countries

Comment: you have to compare Country with single value. like cities from which particular country. Districts from which particular city.

Comment: Is it possible to use LINQ directly on a JSON resultset?

Comment: Yes, result returns as a json array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing Data is a IEnumerable of Countries (please name your variables according to what they present in order to make the code more human understandable)

Also, in the anonymous part of the linq expression you are using both 'i' and 'a' which is not possible. Only 'a' (a city) can be used there.

Try the linq expression underneath and extend any further where needed, this should put you in the right direction.

```
response
.Data
.Where(country => country.Cities != null && country.Cities.Any())
.SelectMany(country => country.Cities)
.Select(city => new {
  CountryId = city.CountryId,
  CountryName = city.CountryName,
  Districts = city.Districts
}).ToList();
```

From your original question it is not totally clear for me what you exactly want to be in the result set, especially the line `Cities = a.Districts` is very confusing.

EDIT (after resultset json was posted in original question).

Use an overload of SelectMany where you can reference both country and city in a anonymous selector method:

```
response
.Data
.Where(country => country.Cities != null && country.Cities.Any())
.SelectMany(country => country.Cities, (country, city) => new {
  CountryId = country.Id,
  CountryName = country.Name,
  Districts = city.Districts
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Response from client does not include ancestor Id inside child model. For example, Country Id does not included at City . Because of the I used `i` tag at linq.

Comment: The classes you included are stating otherwise? How come? Can you include the actual class definitions? Else this is undoable if you post incorrect information.

Comment: I have added some portion of the response model to question

Comment: Please update your question one more time. What do wyou actually want in the result objects? CountryId (or CityId), CountryName (or CityName) and Districts?

Comment: @ I want all of them for zone entity. I have updated the question

Comment: I don't understand you, your questioning is too "wobbly". Sorry but try with the directions I gave you...

Answer (score 0):

If think that your code has more things to valide but problem with "i does not exist in the current context." should be resolve just like below:

```
var newCities = response.Data.Where(i =>i.Cities != null)
                                         .SelectMany(x => x.Cities)
                                         .Select(a => new
                                            {
                                                CountryId = a.Id,
                                                CountryName = a.Name,
                                                Cities = a.Districts
                                            }).ToList();
```

Comment: 'a' is not an Country but a City ;) So it is unjust to state CountryId = a(city).Id